# Is there a way to check for closed window AddThis with event listener?

Tags: javascript, alert, event-listener, addthis

I am using some API functionality with AddThis. I found an API example that will create an alert box when AddThis fully loads on the page. Is there another event listener that I can use to create a popup box after a person closes one of the sharing popup windows? Basically I want to check and see if the AddThis popup window is closed, then trigger another alert box after that. I will post the example and the link to the reference for the API. I do not understand javascript event listeners very well so I apologize for any ignorance in advance.

link to API documentation for AddThis: http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381263-addthis-client-api#events-types

the example used:

```
function addthisReady(evt) {
    alert('AddThis API is fully loaded.');
}

addthis.addEventListener('addthis.ready', addthisReady);
```

Comment: just call one function after another..or use a callback!!

Answer (score 0):

I found it a little difficult to understand your question and If I am not wrong,you want to execute a function after completion of some other function.In this context,I guess you can understand the basic principal and apply it and solve your prolem yourself.

Here is my answer:

> **"Javascript is single threaded".**

*So,what does this means:*

> Javascript runs code sequentially.It is not possible to run two
>   different pieces of Javascript code at the same time because it does
>   not support multithreading.

A simple solution:

```
execute_me_first() ;
execute_me_on_completion();
```

Another solution:

Since functions can be passed as arguments in Javascript, you can pass a function as a callback to execute after the function has completed.

```
function doSomething(callback) {
    execute_me_first() or some code;//This will execute first

    callback('param1','param2');// Call the callback
}

function execute_me_on_completion(param1,param2) {
    // I'm the callback
    alert("hi ,I am executed right after completion of execute_me_first() function");
}

doSomething(execute_me_on_completion);
```

Comment: I will give this a try. Thank you for responding to my question.

Comment: @Phorden:If you understand the fundamental,its bound to run correctly.Dont forget to tick the answer if you find it worthy.good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the addthis.menu.close event, which can be found in our documentation here: http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381263-addthis-client-api#events

The code will look something like this:

```
function addthisClose(evt) {
    alert('AddThis menu has closed.');
}

addthis.addEventListener('addthis.menu.close', addthisClose);
```

Thanks for using AddThis!

Comment: This is not exactly what I am trying to do. This pops up an alert if I hover over the compact menu then when the hover menu closes, it pops up the alert box. I am trying to have an alert box pop up when the AddThis share window is closed. Say someone shares to facebook, then closes the share window, then I would like to pop up an alert box.